# Modifying Anaconda Site-packages location

Tags: python, anaconda, site-packages

After installed Anaconda on the following location "C:\Program Files\anaconda".
My Site-pacakges location is located at "C:\Program Files\anaconda\Lib\site-packages"

Due to the security policy I will not able to install new package into "C:\Program Files\anaconda\Lib\site-packages" folder.

I would like to move my libraray package from "C:\Program Files\anaconda\Lib\site-packages" to my document folder to
"C:\Users\bob\Documents\Lib\site-packages"
and make my anaconda python aware of this new folder.

I have tried to google for quite sometimes but not proper solution.

Please help

Comment: Wen you install anaconda, you are supposed to chose `for me` which uses your user profile instead of `for everyone`.  I think you are going to have to uninstall/reinstall.

Comment: Due to security policy, all app can only run from "C:\Program Files" folder.

Comment: Have a look at [conda enviroments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/create.html). It look like you can create a virtual environment in a specified directory using `--prefix` flag.

Comment: You would still be running apps like `spyder` from the non standard locations.